# Change the servers app.config binding configuration from the wcf client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

How can I *dynamically* set the Security mode like NONE when my nettcpbinding is set in c# code on the client side and on the server my binding is defined in the app.config? How can I change the server`s app.config from the client?

WCF server endpoint:

```
 <service name="Test.ServiceProvider.MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Test.Contracts.IMyService">
              <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="NetTcpMetadataPoint" 
         contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        </service>
```

WCF client endpoint:
the Uri is:

```
net.tcp//localhost:12345/MyService

    1.) What else should my 2nd address be for the 2nd NetTcpBinding?
I guess I just change the MyService to MyEncryptedService and use the same interface? But then I have 2 equal classes/implementations of one interface. Thats stupid actually.
    2.) How does the client binding find its server binding?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short you can't. The server exposes the service and the server dictates its security settings. It will either require security or not but this configuration is done when the server starts hosting of the service and cannot be changed without "stopping" the service. The only way to change it from the client is through some "administration" which will change configuration of the service and restart it but this will have global scope.

If you need both secured and unsecured communication you need to expose two different endpoints. One for secured operations and one for unsecured (if operations on both endpoints are different you should also use different service contracts).

Comment: the admin shall be able to set unencrypted/encrypted nettcp communication. The operations are the same. so when I create 2 nettcpbindings on the client and server side how do I choose the server binding? Does it depend on the name of the binding I choose on the client? so if binding1 is used on client its choosed from the app.config(server) too?

Comment: No it depends on the address of the endpoint. You cannot have two bindings for the same enpoint.

Comment: I marked it as solution Ladislav because its right in general, but it only helps me partially and this is what I do not want to do... ;-)